# How do I call my Socket Send method within my Form from an object? Asychronous Sockets

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets

I have a Form (Form1) that has implemented asynchronous TCP/IP sockets. I have an object(public class MyObject) that I created.

From the Form, I create a array of MyObjects. I then call methods on MyObjects for manipulating data. In MyObjects I have a function:

```
    private void send(string sPacketData)
    {
        if (SocketState.clientSocket != null && SocketState.clientSocket.Connected)
        {
            byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sPacket);
            SocketState.clientSocket.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Form1.SendCallback), this);
        }
    }
```

The problem here is that I am trying to access Form1's SendCallback function with no reference to Form1.

Here is what SendCallback looks like:

```
    public void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve the socket from the state object.
            MyObject mo = (MyObject)ar.AsyncState;
            // Complete sending the data to the remote device.
            int bytesSent = mo.SocketState.clientSocket.EndSend(ar);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Send Callback: " + e.Message + "\r\n");
        }
    }
```

One solution would be to make SendCallback static, but this leads to exceptions where the is not set to an instance of an object.

Is there a different way to do this? Am I barking up the wrong tree? Should I be returning the data I want to send from MyObjects's function calls and then sending from the Form?

Comment: I would suggest putting the call back as a method of MyObject since it is related to that object and to keep it out of the UI code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have `send` take the callback as one of it's parameters, and have `form1` pass in the callback method to `send`.  Alternatively, you could add a property to `MyClass` of type `AsyncCallback` which is set by `Form1` and used in the `send` method.

When creating the callback in `Form1` to pass to `MyObject` use `this.SendCallback` rather than `Form1.SendCallback`.  Or, since `this` is implied, just put in `SendCallback`.

A delegate isn't just a reference to a method, it's a reference to a method and an object instance that should call it (which is much more powerful).  (The object will be `null` for static methods.)  Fortunately, you don't need to explicitly pass the reference to the delegate constructor.  When you enter `this.SomeMethod` or `someObject.MethodOfThatObject` the compiler will translate it into a delegate to that method called on that instance.

Comment: SendCallback exists within Form1. The function Send is within MyObject. So, this.SendCallback does not exist within MyObject.

Comment: The problem with this, MyObject.SomeFunction() is called. SomeFunction() will run a bunch of logic calling other functions and ultimately could get to the Send() function. I would have to pass the callback through many functions and it is not ideal. Could I make the callback a property of MyObject or somthing? and then set it when I create the object.

Comment: @Mausimo You could most certainly make a property of `MyObject` (I really hope it has a better name in reality) that is an `AsyncCallback` delegate, set it in `Form1` and then use it in `send`.

Comment: Yes, it does. Just Trying to simplifyy things as my code has gotten quite big. I will try this.

Comment: Added the relevant additional info from comments into the answer.